# How to find the absolute first match within a column in VBA using Find?

Tags: excel, vba, find

Let's say we have an Excel sheet with text "abc" in cells A1 to A5.

I want to use Find function to search for the first occurrence of "abc" in column A, like this:

```
Columns(1).Find(What:="abc", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

But the above code always returns value 2 and not 1.

It seems to skip the top row of the column if the first match is found there. How to fix this?

I don't want to use loops to search for values because it is too slow on my actual table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported in the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), the search start after the top left cell of the range unless specified othervise in the `After` parameter. To solve this, you can specify said parameter accordingly to your need. In your case, you just have a single column, so you can set the `After` parameter using the `Cells` property like this:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
```

This will return the last cell of the first column. You can use it in your line like this:

```
Columns(1).Find(What:="abc", After:=Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

Be aware that using a `MATCH` function will most likely return the result you are looking for faster (via a better looking line of code). Try something like this:

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match("abc", Columns(1), False)
```